# How i can disable cell of selected dates in times sqaure android datepicker library?

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I am trying to disable selected date in times square datepicker library.

I have added below code in onclicklistener

```
            myCalendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
            calendar = (CalendarPickerView) calendarlayout.findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);
            Button donebutton = (Button) calendarlayout.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
            Date today = new Date();
            calendar.init(today, myCalendar.getTime())
                    .inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.RANGE)
            .withHighlightedDates(getHolidays());
```

getholidays function return arraylist of date.

```
private ArrayList<Date> getHolidays() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
    String dateInString = "21-07-2015";
    String dateInString1 = "22-07-2015";
    String dateInString2 = "23-07-2015";
    ArrayList<Date> holidays = new ArrayList<>();
    Date date, date1, date2 = null;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
        holidays.add(date);
        date1 = sdf.parse(dateInString1);
        holidays.add(date1);
        date2 = sdf.parse(dateInString2);
        holidays.add(date2);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return holidays;
}
```

How i can disable these dates cell inactive(non selectable/clickable)

I am using this library https://github.com/square/android-times-square

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you call init() it clears all the old dates selected. If you look at the init implementation it clears all the selected cells. Example as shown below. Hope it helped

```
    public void initializeCalendar(){ // or reset Calendar
       Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
       nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

       Date today = new Date();

       calendar.init(today, nextYear.getTime())
            .withSelectedDate(today);
    }
```